# Using Cling to compile Python C++ extensions

Tags: python, c++, swig, jit, cling

Is it possible to use Cling for compiling C++ python extensions (wrapped using SWIG)?

Either by hand or perhaps making a setup that allows a JIT compilation of the C++ extensions without needing to compile C++ code manually?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... Yes cling can compile any C++ code that clang can compile.